# How to get current logged in user in asp.net mvc without using membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have implemented the Login and Registration Forms in ASP.Net MVC4 without using the Membership provider .. Now i need to get the currently logged in user details.How should i do this.
Need some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of details? UserName, UserId, etc.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look once..may this helpful for you 
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.